# How can we search the records in a singly linked list?

Tags: c++

so for my program, we are using singly linked list and i'm having trouble find records. 
we have hard-coded two records with rating 5 for example. When we first start my program and search for them, both records show up, but when we enter a new record with a different rating then it says rating not found or address not found.
What is the problem in our code ?

p.s - btw this is a group assignment and my group mate did this, so i'm just trying to figure out how can i fix this...

```
struct tutor
{
    int tutorid, rate;
    string  tutoraddress;
    tutor* next;
};

class record
{
public:
    //head as first in node
    tutor* head;
    tutor* tail;
    //Get size of node
    int getSize;

    //Constructor to flush and renew the value of node to null, and size to 0
    record()
    {
        this->head = NULL;
        this->tail = NULL;
        this->getSize = 0;
    }
    void exist()
    {
        tutor* n = new tutor;
        //First
        n->tutorid = 1;
        n->tutoraddress = "Puchong";
        n->rate = 5;
        n->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = n;
        }
        else
        {
            tail = head;
            while (tail->next != NULL)
            {
                tail = tail->next;
            }
            tail->next = n;
        }
        getSize++;
    }

    void exist1()
    {
        tutor* n = new tutor;
        //Second
        n->tutorid = 2;
        n->tutoraddress = "Puchong";
        n->rate = 5;
        n->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = n;
        }
        else
        {
            tail = head;
            while (tail->next != NULL)
            {
                tail = tail->next;
            }
            tail->next = n;
        }
        getSize++;
    }
int find()
    {
        //create n node and assign to head
        //then traverse to end of list to find the
        //search value
        int ch = 0;
        int rating = 0;
        int id = 0;
        string address;

        while (true)
        {
            cout << "\n1>Find ID\n";
            cout << "2>Find rating\n";
            cout << "3>Find address\n";
            cout << "4>Quit\n";
            cout << "Select menu: ";
            cin >> ch;

            if (ch == 1)
            {
                cout << "\nMenu selected: " << ch << "\n";
                cout << "Enter ID: ";
                cin >> id;

                tutor* n = head;
                while (n != NULL)
                {
                    if (n->tutorid == id)
                    {
                        cout << "\nID: " << n->tutorid << "\n";
                        system("pause");
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        n = n->next;
                    }
                }
                cout << "\nID not found\n";
                system("pause");
                return false;
            }
            else if (ch == 2)
            {
                cout << "\nMenu selected: " << ch << "\n";
                cout << "Enter rating: ";
                cin >> rating;

                tutor* n = head;
                while (n != NULL)
                {
                    if (n->rate == rating)
                    {
                        cout << "\nID: " << n->tutorid << "\n";
                        n = n->next;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        n = n->next;
                        cout << "\nRate not found\n";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (ch == 3)
            {
                cout << "\nMenu selected: " << ch << "\n";
                cout << "Enter address: ";
                cin >> address;

                tutor* n = head;
                while (n != NULL)
                {
                    if (n->tutoraddress == address)
                    {
                        cout << "\nID: " << n->tutorid << "\n";
                        n = n->next;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        n = n->next;
                        cout << "\nAddress not found\n";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\nEnd\n";
                system("pause");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I am afraid I know the answer ("this is for our course, and we are not allowed to use the standard library..."), but why don't you save yourself all the hassle and use [`<forward_list>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) and [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm), *perfect* matches for what you're doing, and well-tested? If the answer **is** "we may not use the standard library", my standard suggestion -- find a course that is actually teaching C++, not "reimplementing the standard library in 'C with classes'"...

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use `this->` when referring to member variables or methods.  The constructor is no exception.  You only need `this->` when differentiating member variable from parameters that have the same name.

Comment: Just going through the code quickly -- to find a node in a linked list doesn't take a 50 line function.  Removing all of the prompts, the find code should be no more than 10 lines, and that is maximum.  Advice -- take out all of that unimportant code in the `find` function (such as the prompts), and recode that function to take the paramters required to do a find, and do *just that* -- `find` and return the node if found.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your code, watching values in variables.  Also with a linked list, I recommend drawing the list as you debug.  Please edit your post with the text results of your debugging session.

Comment: You're `exist` function creates an unnecessary node.  Also, the function doesn't compare any of the fields when following the links.

Comment: First: don't roll your own linked list. Use the classes provided by the standard library. Second: to find something, use `std::find` (and friends). Third: try to never use linked lists unless you *really* have to. Their performance is terrible.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Generally worthless advice for what is very likely a homework assignment where students code data structures to get very familiar with them.

Comment: @sweenish feel free to *ignore* my *comment*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Same to you, huh?

Comment: You are using your `tail` pointer incorrectly. It isn't used to iterate and find the last node, it always points to the last node allowing insertions in O(1) time. Your `tail = head = n;` goes under `if (head == NULL)`

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Performance of linked lists vs. other containers very much depends on usage. If you keep adding, removing, and rearranging large objects, a linked list can very easily outperform a vector (which, admittedly, is the go-to container in the general case).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about searching a linked list, here is an example function to search the list by `tutoraddress`:

```
tutor * record::find_by_tutor_address(const std::string& key)
{
  tutor * p_node = head;
  while (p_node != nullptr)
  {
    if (p_node->tutoraddress == key)
    {
      break;
    }
    p_node = p_node->next;
  }
  return p_node;
}
```

Searching by the other fields can use a similar function.

The fundamental process is to start at the head node and follow the links until the node is found.  The function will return `nullptr` if the key is not found or it will return a pointer to the node that contains the *key*.